# Using WCF to send a signed Request and receive an unsigned Response

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, ws-security

I'm working with a .NET dev team who are trying to interface with a web service that uses WS-Security, and although the service requires signed requests it only returns unsigned responses.

The team knows of a way to call the service using WSE, but they're required to use WCF, so can anyone suggest how to configure WCF to send signed requests and receive unsigned responses?

TIA

Comment: I need to do this same thing, but in WSE only.  Would you share how you did this with WSE?

Comment: @Corey - I'd really love to help, but I can't remember which team member solved the WSE solution and unfortunately the team spread on the wind a while ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Microsoft Hotfix KB971493](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493/): A hotfix that enables WCF to send secured messages and to receive unsecured responses, and to send unsecured messages and to receive secured responses, is available for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) does not have the functionality to send secured messages and then receive unsecured responses, or to send unsecured messages and receive secured responses. The hotfix that is described in this article adds a new enableUnsecuredResponse attribute.