# Getting the digitally signed message from the opration response

Tags: wcf

Client, which is communicating with a WCF service using transport security mode, has to keep records of original digitally signed responses along with the decrypted data.
Is there a way in WCF to get access the signed data from a response, or do I need to explicitly pass the signed data in the response message itself.

Comment: Maybe you can check these documents to find a solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-set-up-a-signature-confirmation && https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277798/using-wcf-to-send-a-signed-request-and-receive-an-unsigned-response?rq=1 && https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-transport-security-and-message-credentials?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I wasn't able to find something that would help me. Thanks for the suggestion.